# how to handle connections to hub across the project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have multiple roles in my project , i have to make connections to hubs across the project ..

ex : In my project , Roles : Receptionist, Doctor

When receptionist adds an appointment to particular doctor, then i have to notify and update the appointments list of a particular doctor in the page(where doctor is the role)

Is it good to put entire server methods in one hub class , if not then how to make connection bt multiple hubs

Can any one suggest how to handle this issue ?

Comment: Have you looked into using groups on your hub? One approach would be to add the client with a Role(Group) when the client connects to hub. By doing this you could then dispatch to the proper group (doctor that matches the role you want) and signalr will magically handle this for you. If u think that would help, i can provide an example where I do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same connection to access multiple hubs.

.NET client
var hubConnection = new HubConnection(url);
var hubProxy1 = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("Hub1");
var hubProxy2 = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("Hub2");
await hubConnection.Start();

JS client
$.connection.myHub1.server.method1();
$.connection.myHub2.server.method2();
$.connection.hub.start();